# WebRTC Safari: No reception if no emission (more precisely no ICE candidate callback)

Tags: safari, webrtc, mobile-safari

The following JS fiddle shows that Safari doesn't want to receive a video stream if a local video track has not been added. More precisely, the ICE candidate callback never happens.

https://jsfiddle.net/2r5mocfz/

- Using Chrome: Click on "Without Local Camera", you are getting the ICE candidate callback with the alert messages.
- Using Safari: Click on "Without Local Camera", you are **NOT** getting the ICE candidate callback. You are getting it only if you click on "With Local Camera" and accept to use your local camera.

The javascript code is:

```
function handleICECandidateEvent(event) {
    alert("ICE callback");
    console.log(event);
}

async function start_(arg) {
    alert("Starting " + arg);
    let peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection({iceServers:[{urls: 'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302'}]});
    peerConnection.onicecandidate = handleICECandidateEvent;
  if (arg) {
        const s = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:true});
        s.getTracks().forEach(track => {peerConnection.addTrack(track, s);});
  }
    const offer = await peerConnection.createOffer({offerToReceiveAudio: true, offerToReceiveVideo: true});
    await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
}
```

Is there any workaround? I would like on Safari to receive a WebRTC video stream without having to involve a local camera with its permission request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safari choose not implement the "legacy" offerToReceive* options described in https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#legacy-configuration-extensions

You can either port your code to use addTransceiver or use the [webrtc-adapter](https://github.com/webrtchacks/adapter) package which polyfills this.